# How to save/apply the data types from each cells from multiple excel sheets to a merged excel sheet using VBA through MS-Access?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

In MS Access I am using VBA to iterate multiple Excel sheets, I then perform a left join on 5 sheets based on the shared join key "Unique Transaction ID". After that is merged I save that to the end of the Excel file. So now I have a sheet that is a merge of those 5 sheets. The problem is I need to preserve/apply or at least be able to reference the data types of the previous sheets.

What I tried doing is after the left join is performed, then create a dictionary that references all the correct ranges of the sheets and applies the data types found there. But this doesn't work because it seems to just assume one data type and apply it to the column. There could be many different data types in a column, I need either a granular way to apply the data types to the merged sheet, or a way to reference the previous sheets with the correct orientation of how the merged sheet is setup.

Here is what I've tried. This is my left join code for the sheets and my attempt at using a dictionary to apply the data types:

```
    Dim ls_last_row As Long
    Dim cs_last_row As Long
    Dim e_sheet_last_row As Long
    Dim p_sheet_last_row As Long
    
    Set ls = objFile.Worksheets("2. sheet")
    Set cs = objFile.Worksheets("3. sheet")
    Set es = objFile.Worksheets("4. sheet")
    Set ps = objFile.Worksheets("5. sheet")
    
    l_sheet_last_row = ls.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    cs_last_row = cs.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    e_sheet_last_row = es.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    p_sheet_last_row = ps.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    
    ' loading in sheet2 to ms-access table
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "tmp_sheet2", filePath, True, "2. sheet!A1:AU" & loan_sheet_last_row
    ' loading in sheet3 to ms-access table
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "tmp_sheet3", filePath, True, "3. sheet!A1:I" & cs_last_row
    ' loading in sheet4 to ms-access table
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "tmp_sheet4", filePath, True, "4. sheet!A1:H" & e_sheet_last_row
    ' loading in shset5 to ms-access table
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "tmp_sheet5", filePath, True, "5. sheet!A1:D" & p_sheet_last_row
    
    'Execute SQL statement to perform the join
    Dim strSql As String
    strSql = "SELECT sheet2.*, sheet3.*, sheet4.*, sheet5.* " _
            & "FROM ((tmp_sheet2 AS sheet2 " _
            & "LEFT JOIN tmp_sheet3 AS sheet3 ON CSTR(sheet2.[Unique Transaction ID]) = CSTR(sheet3.[Unique Transaction ID])) " _
            & "LEFT JOIN tmp_sheet4 AS sheet4 ON CSTR(sheet2.[Unique Transaction ID]) = CSTR(sheet4.[Unique Transaction ID])) " _
            & "LEFT JOIN tmp_sheet5 AS sheet5 ON CSTR(sheet2.[Unique Transaction ID]) = CSTR(sheet5.[Unique Transaction ID])"
    
    'Create new table with join results
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Dim tableName As String
    tableName = "joined_table"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO " & tableName & " FROM (" & strSql & ")"
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE joined_table DROP COLUMN [sheet3_Unique Transaction ID]"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE joined_table DROP COLUMN [sheet4_Unique Transaction ID]"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE joined_table DROP COLUMN [sheet5_Unique Transaction ID]"
    
    'Add joined_table to ms-access
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & tableName)
    
    Set newSheet = objFile.Worksheets.Add(After:=objFile.Worksheets(objFile.Worksheets.Count))
    newSheet.Name = "2. Transaction Data"
    
    ' Copy header names to new sheet
    Dim headerRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Set headerRange = newSheet.Range("A1")
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        If i = 0 Then
            headerRange.Offset(0, i) = "Unique Transaction ID"
        Else
            headerRange.Offset(0, i) = rs.Fields(i).Name
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Copy data to new sheet
    headerRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
    
    ' create dictionary to store row numbers for IDs in Sheet 2
    Dim idDict As Object
    Set idDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 2 To loan_sheet_last_row
        idDict.Add ls.Cells(i, 1).Value, i
    Next i
    
    ' iterate sheet 2, store its data types and apply to newSheet
    Dim j As Long
    For i = 2 To loan_sheet_last_row
    Dim id As Variant
    id = ls.Cells(i, 1).Value ' assume ID is in column 1
    Dim matchRow As Variant
    If idDict.Exists(id) Then
        Dim rowNumber As Long
        rowNumber = idDict(id)
        For j = 1 To 47 'iterate from column B to AU (2 to 47)
            Dim dataType As String
            dataType = TypeName(ls.Cells(i, j).Value)
            newSheet.Cells(rowNumber, j).NumberFormat = GetNumberFormat(dataType)
        Next j
    End If
    Next i
    
    ' iterate Sheet3, store its data types and apply to newSheet
    Dim k As Long
    For i = 2 To cs_last_row ' start from row 2 to skip header
    id = cs.Cells(i, 1).Value ' assuming ID is in column 1
    If idDict.Exists(id) Then
        rowNumber = idDict(id)
        For k = 2 To 9 ' iterate from colum B to column I
            dataType = TypeName(cs.Cells(i, k).Value)
            newSheet.Cells(rowNumber, k + 46).NumberFormat = GetNumberFormat(dataType)
        Next k
    End If
    Next i
    
    ' iterate Sheet4, store its data types and apply to newSheet
    Dim q As Long
    For i = 2 To e_sheet_last_row ' start from row 2 to skip header
    id = es.Cells(i, 1).Value ' assuming ID is in column 1
    If idDict.Exists(id) Then
        rowNumber = idDict(id)
        For q = 2 To 8 ' iterate from column B to column H
            dataType = TypeName(es.Cells(i, q).Value)
            newSheet.Cells(rowNumber, q + 54).NumberFormat = GetNumberFormat(dataType)
        Next q
    End If
    Next i
    
    ' iterate Sheet5, store its data types and apply to newSheet
    Dim p As Long
    For i = 2 To p_sheet_last_row ' start from row 2 to skip header
    id = ps.Cells(i, 1).Value ' assuming ID is in column 1
    If idDict.Exists(id) Then
        rowNumber = idDict(id)
        For p = 2 To 4 ' iterate from column B to column D
            dataType = TypeName(ps.Cells(i, p).Value)
            newSheet.Cells(rowNumber, p + 61).NumberFormat = GetNumberFormat(dataType)
        Next p
    End If
    Next i
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
```

Here is the GetNumberFormat method:

```
Function GetNumberFormat(dataType As String) As String
'**********************************************************************
' Listed below is Excel's data types and VBA's NumberFormat equivalent
' General: General
' Number: 0
' Currency:    $#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00
' Accounting:  _($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)
' Date: m/d/yyyy
' Time:        [$-F400]h:mm:ss am/pm
' Percentage:  0.00%
' Fraction:    # ?/?
' Scientific: 0#
' String:        @
' Special:     ;;
' Custom:      #,##0_);[Red](#,##0)
'**********************************************************************
    Select Case dataType
        Case "String"
            GetNumberFormat = "@"
        Case "Date"
            GetNumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        Case "Currency"
            GetNumberFormat = "$#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00"
        Case "Double"
            GetNumberFormat = "0"
        Case "Integer"
            GetNumberFormat = "0"
        Case "Accounting"
            GetNumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* " - "??_);_(@_)"
        Case "Percentage"
            GetNumberFormat = "0.00%"
        Case Else
            GetNumberFormat = "General"
    End Select
End Function
```

What I tried posted. Was expected that the data types for each cell would be preserved, but instead each column gets defaulted to a specific type depending on the first data type that VBA encounters. Need a way to ensure that each cell's data type is preserved.

Comment: Excel is not a database. Excel doesn't really have data types - which is why multiple different 'types' can be in same column. Cells have formatting. Either write data one cell at a time and apply format to each cell or force everything to be treated as text with leading apostrophe. Or maybe Copy/Paste with Format.

Comment: @June7 when I say data types, I mean things shown in the GetNumberFormat method. How could I write the data one cell at a time and apply formatting to each cell. Also what would forcing everything to be treated as text with leading apostrophe do? Copy/Paste with format, is this the same as PasteSpecial shown here: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/value-paste-pastespecial/

Comment: Reading/Writing one cell at a time would be tedious to code and probably perform slowly. I did some testing and can't figure out a way for Excel formula to distinguish between numbers as dates and just numbers. This would be necessary in order to determine if number should be converted to a date string with apostrophe prefix. Apparently, no intrinsic Excel function to get cell format, requires VBA such as you have coded. Yes, PasteSpecial. Perils of bad data schema.

Comment: @June7 Here is what I use after "headerRange.Offset(1,0).CopyRecordset rs. But I a pop-up error saying paste is not the same size as destination: headerRange.Offset(1,0).CopyFromRecordset rs .....         ' PasteSpecial for formatting
        newSheet.Range("B2").Select
        newSheet.Range(newSheet.Range("B2"), newSheet.Cells(newSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, newSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Comment: Not seeing Range Copy. Example: `Range("A1:D200").Copy` then `Range("A12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`. However, this will not get data from 5 sheets correctly associated.

Comment: @June7 Thanks. Why would data from sheet 4 not get correctly associated?

Comment: Wait, I see now you are importing to Access then joining in query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I can suggest is to use VBA to 'scrub' the worksheets so that Access import will accept mixed-data columns. Following is example of quick test on a small range to modify number/date values with apostrophe prefix so they will be treated as string.

```
Sub FixData()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A1:A25")
    c.Value = "'" & c.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am first loading the sheets into Access the performing the left join. The code you posted, where would this fit into the existing code?

Comment: I was able to get part of the code working by using this:         Dim formatRange As Range
        Set formatRange = objFile.Worksheets("2. sheet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        formatRange.Copy
        newSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats ... this correctly pastes the data types into the merged sheet. Problem is that aside from 2. sheet, all other sheets due to the left join could occur on different rows, so I need to figure out how to account for where to paste each row for the proceeding sheets.

Comment: I already backed off of the copy/paste idea for that reason. Also, that will not help for Access import because data is still mixed types in column. Modify Excel data so all is treated as text then import.

Comment: Access import I dont really use. Since I was able to paste the values to the excel sheet, and all data types are there. In ms-access vba, I just iterate upon that newSheet, so long as the values and corresponding data type is there that is what matters. Sheet2 is good, but for Sheet3, and Sheet4 the rows have to match with the corresponding unique transaction ID of Sheet2, any thoughts on how that is done?

Comment: With complex code that loops sheets 3 and 4 rows, searches the new sheet for ID and copy/pastes associated data one row at a time. You don't want to eventually import into Access? That was just a means to an end which is a merged spreadsheet? I suggest that is still probably the easiest approach. Fix data, import, query, export back to Excel.